# Is there a way to generate new span elements for each value we iterate in *ngFor Angular 8?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, loops, ngfor

I want to generate a span element for each saved tag from my collection tag's array.
I use firebase and get in *ngFor loop i get one big span element with all saved tags separated by comma, instead of getting a span for each tag. Is there any way that i can't prevent this from happening. Also i have created an interface for Saved.
Thanks in advance.

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{saved?.title}}</h5>
                <hr />
                <div *ngFor="let tag of saved.tags">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{saved?.tags}}</span>
                </div>
                <hr /> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  offset-4 col-md-4">View</a>

            </div>
        </div>

//Saved interface in Saved.ts file
export interface Saved {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  tags: string[];
}
```

Comment: Using `{{saved?.tags}}` puts them all in there for each iteration.  Just use `{{tag}}` to get the one for that iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Straight to the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try having your code like this. This should make the span element repeat rather than the div and then make sure to reference the individual tag rather than the array inside.

If the tag has a name / title attribute swap `{{ tag }}` for `{{ tag.title}}`

looking at the interface its just `{{ tag }}`.

```
<div>
  <span *ngFor="let tag of saved.tags" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">
    {{tag}}
  </span>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to Angular docs on using `*ngFor` to display data.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are referencing the array inside your `*ngFor`. So, as a result, you should see the whole list of n tags, for n times. If you switch from `{{saved?.tags}}` to `{{tag}}`. You will see one div per tag including one span and a single tag inside.

So for getting one span per tag, use it like the following:

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{saved?.title}}</h5>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" *ngFor="let tag of saved.tags">
                    {{tag}}
                </span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary  offset-4 col-md-4">View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```